# MSXML ClassFactory cannot supply requested class Error

Tags: c#, sql, xml, web-services

I'm having an issue trying to call a web service from stored procedure.

```
sp_OACreate 'Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP'
```

The error code is 0x80040111 - ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

The source returned when I run sp_OAGetErrorInfo is msxml3.dll

I found msxml3.dll in \Windows\System32\
I have tried to register this dll using regsvr32.exe with no help.

Any thought would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT:
The server has the followings installed
Windows Server 2003 R2
SQL 2008 R2
Internet Explorer 8

Comment: How this is related to C#? (Note that MSXML is not supported to be run inside .Net processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update. The problem seems to resolve itself. It could have been after a server reboot. I have to continue to monitor it.